# Error: Path must be a string. Received undefined / codorva add platform android

Tags: cordova-plugin

quando vou gerar no codorva a plataforma android, ele começa a instalar os plugins, mas no whitelist ele ocorre o seguinte erro?

```
    Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for android

 This plugin is only applicable for versions of cordova-android greater than 4.0. If you have a previous platform version, you do *not* need this plugin since the whitelist will be built in.

    **Error: Path must be a string. Received undefined.**
```

Por que isto acontece? Como posso sanar?

Comment: Você precisa atualizar o *Cordova* para versão *4.0* ou para uma versão superior a ela.

Comment: C:\projetos\primeiro>cordova platform version android
Installed platforms:

Available platforms:
  android ~6.3.0
  blackberry10 ~3.8.0 (deprecated)
  browser ~5.0.0
  ios ~4.5.1
  osx ~4.0.1
  ubuntu ~4.3.4 (deprecated)
  webos ~3.7.0
  windows ~5.0.0
  www ^3.12.0

C:\projetos\primeiro>cordova -v
7.1.0

Comment: esta na versao 7.1.0.
e o codorva-android 6.3.0

Comment: Para qual versão do *Android* você está utilizando esse plugin?

Comment: <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
        <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23" />

Comment: percebi que meu erro está em algum path aqui, estou olhando e não achei erros nas variaveis de ambiente.

Comment: Esta utilizando algum *Framework* ?? *Ionic* ?

Comment: não, nenhum plugin a mais só exportei do intel xdk, fiz o que tinha que fazer, mas agora não compila

Comment: @Morvy poderia colocar aqui onde você achou esse path que você conseguiu corrigir o problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, arrumei uma solução. Quanto aos erros ocorridos por causa da versão e tal, este não tem problema, ainda sim é gerado, o que travava todos o processo era este erro:

```
Error: Path must be a string. Received undefined.
```

achei um path aleatório, da qual nem tinha me tocado o por que estava ali, ou para que servia. Simplesmente removi e ele compilou perfeitamente, agora vamos testar para ver se gera o app e rode, obrigado.